# TSplicedFont failed creating descriptor for El Capitan

Tags: macos, recovery, error, font, disk-format

So I've bought used macbook air, wanted to format it to delete all traces of previous user.
Unfortunately after trying to reinstall I get spammed with this error message:

```
Language Chooser[416:4031] TSplicedFont failed creating descriptor for:
```

and list fonts that are missing.
I know that possible fix is to download system installer from app store, make a bootable usb drive and copy those missing fonts in there

```
https://noto-website-2.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/Noto-unhinted.zip
```

but I don't have access to app store so I can't actually make it.
Left installer for the night - nothing.

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before. From memory it was an issue for a lot of people when trying to install El Capitan from an external USB drive, rather than from the internal boot drive. For some users it would resolve itself by leaving it for a few hours, but obviously you've already tried that.

There's a couple of workarounds I've seen, briefly summarised below:

- **Download/install the Google Noto fonts** - This was a simple fix for many users. Basically you [download](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) the Google Noto fonts and then manually install them onto the USB drive at the following location: `\System\Library\Fonts`. I don't recall now, but you may need to actually create the Fonts folder in that location. Anyway, once installed, try installing again. (Note: you may need to
- **Install to an external drive first** - This one takes a lot longer to do. Basically you install El Capitan onto an external drive first and then create an exact clone of it onto your internal drive. You can use software such as [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/) or [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) to do this.

Another option, although you don't specify which model of MacBook Air you bought, is to try booting up with the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys held down. This combination *should* reinstall the **macOS version that shipped with your Mac**, or the version *closest* to it that is still available. If that version is El Capitan, then you're set. If it's an earlier OS, then boot into that and run the installer while you're booted in.